# Unable to connect to internet using self established VPN on remote server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, internet

I am using a college network which blocks all connections except tcp on ports 80/443. I have a server running somewhere in USA.

I followed this tutorial to setup vpn server-

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04

So I am pretty much able to connect to the vpn network according to the logs on client side, but if I try to open google (for namesake), browser just continues to be in a state of "Connecting to google.com"

When I tried to `traceroute google.com` it was supposedly blocked at `ip-208-109-112-234.ip.secureserver.net (208.109.112.234)`. This block is definitely not a block by the college network as when I try to traceroute without VPN, it follows a totally different ip route.

Please help me with the possible reasons and solutions to this problem?

PS- If any logs/configs are required, I'd be happy to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a VPN server by itself does not make all your traffic go through it. A VPN simply sets up a point-to-point tunnel between two hosts.

If your goal is to simply get your Internet browser to use your server in the US as a proxy, I suggest installing Squid3 in the server you have in the States and configure it as an HTTP proxy. You should be able to find many tutorials online that can direct you on how to do this.